How can I detect and set language dynamically from the URL?
I’m working on a React application where I need to detect the user’s language from the URL (/en/home, /ar/login) and dynamically set it in i18next for localization. I also want to ensure that if the language is invalid or not present in the URL, it defaults to 'en'.
Here’s the relevant code for my i18next initialization:
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';


i18n
    .use(Backend)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        debug: false,
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false,
        },
        backend: {
            loadPath: '/api/translations/{{lng}}',
        },
       
    });`

export default i18n;

And I am using the following route structure in React Router:
<Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
But this isn't working as expected. Can someone help me with:

Correctly validating the language code from the URL.
Ensuring the language is set dynamically in i18next.
Defaulting to 'en' if the language is invalid.


You're using LanguageDetector which suppose to support language in url. Isn't working?
